# Unable to select first p

Tags: jquery

I want to add class of first p element with the help of jquery. but it's not selection first p element. But when i pass 2 in nth child it's select first p.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>:jQuery Attribute:</title>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style>
    .one {font-size:20px;}
    .second {color:red;}

</style>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</head>
 <body>
    <h2>All jQuery Attribute</h2>
    <p class="one">First Para </p>
    <p class="one">Second Para </p>
    <p class="one">Third Para </p>
    <p class="one">Fourth Para </p>
    <p class="one">Fifth Para </p>


<script>
    $('p:nth-child(1)').addClass('second');
</script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `$('p').first().addClass('second');`

Comment: Or `$('p:nth-of-type(1)').addClass('second');`

Comment: `p:nth-child(1)` is targeting first child which is `p` element. BUT there is no `p` element which is first child of its parent

Comment: When you used jquery, why don't use jquery selector? Use `$('p:first')`.

Comment: @A.Wolff God damn inconsistent indexes :) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you mistake `:nth-child` with `:nth-of-type`

`p:nth-child(1)` returns `p` that is first child

in your markup first child is `h2` so nothing gets selected

then, if you change that to `:nth-child(2)` it selects first `p` which is indeed the second element in `<body>`

Answer (score 1):

Try `$("p:first").addClass('second');`

Comment: `p:first` is jQuery extension and it is not recommended to use it - see additional notes here: http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

Comment: @pwolaq not recommended? where/why?

Comment: quote from the site above: *Because :first is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :first cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. To achieve the best performance when using :first to select elements, first select the elements using a pure CSS selector, then use .filter(":first")*

Answer (score 0):

I very often like to use `.eq()` because of its simplicity and readability

```
$("p").eq(0).addClass("second")
```

.eq() counts from 0 being the first found item in the selection

Comment: `p:first` is jQuery extension and it is not recommended to use it

Answer (score 0):

Try `$($("p")[0]).addClass("second");`

Answer (score -2):

Try to use:

```
jQuery('p').eq(0).addClass('second');
```